# Android: Manage multiple push notification in device of an app

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I am developing an application in which i implemented **Push notification** functionality.
My code of **onMessage** - GCMIntentService.java is:

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent data) {
    String message = data.getExtras().getString("message");

    displayMessage(context, message);
    generateNotification(context, message);
}
```

And code of **generateNotification** -

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, GCMMessageView.class);

    notificationIntent.putExtra("message", message);
    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

This code is working fine. I am getting push message and notification.

**=>But when i send more then one message the notification gets over write. And i am able to see only last notification in status bar.**

The **need** of application is that -  if i send **more then one** notification then all should be **display in status bar.**

So please guide me what should i do for that in my code.

Answer (score 10):

Try to put different notification id (i.e. nid) in intent and notify instead of 0 for each new notification this will prevent over writing your notification

```
  PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, nid,notificationIntent, 0);
```

and

`notificationManager.notify(nid, notification);`

Hope this will help you

Comment: You saved my day. When several push notifications were delivered, only last pending intent was executed for every notification. After I changed 0 to notificationId, it has fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Get random numbers:

```
Random random = new Random();
int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
```

Instead of:

```
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

use:

```
notificationManager.notify(m, notification);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your `Notification ID` when you fire a `Notification.` in

```
notificationManager.notify(ID, notification);
```

**How?**

To set up a notification so it can be different, issue it with a notification ID by calling `NotificationManager.notify(ID, notification).` To change this notification once you've issued it, create a `NotificationCompat.Builder` object, build a `Notification` object from it, and issue the `Notification` with the `Different ID` you are not used previously.

If the previous notification is still visible, the system updates it from the contents of the `Notification object`. If the previous notification has been dismissed, a new notification is created instead.

For more information go to official [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Answer (score 2):

hello you need to pass unique notification id in notify method. 
Below is the code for pass unique notification id:

```
//"CommonUtilities.getValudeFromOreference" is the method created by me to get value from savedPreferences.
String notificationId = CommonUtilities.getValueFromPreference(context, Global.NOTIFICATION_ID, "0");
int notificationIdinInt = Integer.parseInt(notificationId);

notificationManager.notify(notificationIdinInt, notification);

// will increment notification id for uniqueness
notificationIdinInt = notificationIdinInt + 1;
CommonUtilities.saveValueToPreference(context, Global.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationIdinInt + "");
//Above "CommonUtilities.saveValueToPreference" is the method created by me to save new value in savePreferences.
```

Let me know if you need more detail information or any query. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
notificationManager.notify(Different_id_everytime, notification);
```