# MobileFirst Plaform v7.1 - Manage multiple push notification

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

When implementing Push notification using IBM MobileFirst Platform. I noticed that when i send more then one message, the notification gets over write each other. And i am able to see only last notification in status bar.

The issue is the same with this article for Android phone. It recommends to use different Notification ID.

[Android: Manage multiple push notification in device of an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22858315/android-manage-multiple-push-notification-in-device-of-an-app)

The question is: how I can fix this problem in IBM MFP v7.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

This blog post shows how you can override the default push notifications implementation by adding your own, that will create the "Inbox" style notifications: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/inboxstyle_notifications_in_android?lang=en

If you do not want to create your own notification implementation, you can add the following property to the wlclient.properties file in your generated Android project:

`showAllNotificationsInTray=true`

This properly is available only if your are using the latest 7.1 iFix from IBM Fix Central.